# How to use Dixie Observable from a React application developed using hook?

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb, dexie

In my application I want to use **Dixie.js** to read/write data into IndexDB from my Webworker & **Dixie Observable** to listen event from main thread **(React functional component which uses hook)** instead of worker **postMessage**.
Dixie.js documentation is very clear but Dixie Observable documentation is not that clear

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie-observable

Provided code sample not working from React. I will appreciated for any help/input.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question contains numerous spelling errors, the fixes for which were apparently rejected by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page instead: https://dexie.org/docs/dexie-react-hooks/useLiveQuery()

Dexie.Observable is something else.